# How to set a Java project facet to 12?

Tags: java, eclipse, facet, eclipse-wtp, jboss-tools

I'm trying to set up a JavaEE project with Java 12 in Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11). I installed support for Java 12 and the following web tools:

[image]

If I set the compiler and jdk to 12, I get an error that it does not match the facet number which is 11. I don't have a way to choose 12:

[image]

I installed JBoss Tools too which support Java 12:

[image]

Why can't I choose java facet 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you had to patch JDT support for 12 onto 2019-03, a Java 12 Facet doesn't exist yet. We're looking into having one for 2019-06, pending resources.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way for me to use 12 in my server anyway, without "applying" the facet? I would like to test the preview switch expressions there and the compiler level must be 12.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  But version 12 will definitely be in the upcoming release.

Comment: I see that there are now both 12 and 13 facets.